# Sneak Attack after the first Attack while flanking

Tags: rogue, pathfinder-2e, sneak-attack

In Pathfinder 2e it is possible to make 3 attacks each round. Let us say I flank with my other party member. Can I sneak the second and third attack as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Yes

There is nothing to suggest otherwise in the text from Sneak Attack, which states:

> If you Strike a creature that has the flat-footed condition with an agile or finesse melee weapon, an agile or finesse unarmed attack, or a ranged weapon attack, you deal an extra  precision damage.

The once per round rule is from D&D 5e, and only from there as far as I'm aware. But it's 100% not PF2e.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just one additional comment. Isnt the Twin Feint than redundant?

Comment: @ruedi, quite often you can't flank (or get flat-footed in other ways). Twin Faint is useful in those cases. You get SA at least on the second attack

Comment: The main benefit of Twin Feint is that you can choose your positioning more easily and don't have to roll to gain Flat-Footed. There are cases where a target may be immune to flanking, or you may want to be near an ally (say, Champion with their damage reduction reaction) for one reason or another; it also could chain into abilities such as Thief rogues' to keep the target flat-footed without flanking